# rotating lines around the origin?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

If you have a line that goes through the origin and you rotate it around the origin, will the resulting line also go through the origin?
Is this true for every line that you rotate if it goes through the origin?
I just need a simple answer, no proofs are needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A line that goes through the origin has this form:
$$y=mx$$
Rotating it by $\alpha$ degrees is achieved by
$$y=\frac{m+\tan{\alpha}}{1-m\tan{\alpha}}x$$
And we can see that is still goes through the origin ($(x,y)=(0,0)$)